# History.js vs Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap, history-api, javascript

Встречалась ли вам такая ситуация, когда приходилось сайт, построенный на Twitter Bootstrap 3 подружить из библиотекой [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)?
Дело в том, что у Bootstrap есть плагины такие как `Modal` и `Tabs`, которые используют для вызова хеш-URL (к примеру `href="#myModal"... </a>`).
А [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) в свое время также перехватывает эти хеши и в итоге ничего не происходит!
Интересует, есть ли у кого-то универсальное решение для этой проблемы?

Comment: вопрос хороший, сходу не ответишь, наверное надо хачить  bootstrap - запретить ему смотреть на hashurl, а в обработчике событий history.js  сделать вызовы функций bootstrap, бонусом получите нормальные url для bootstrap в тех браузерах, в которых поддерживается history api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем я нашел выход из этой ситуации. Может не совсем подходящий для всех, но мне подошел! History.js реагирует на атрибут href только для тегов A (ссылки). Если нам нужно вывести кнопку для вызова модального окна, по сути это не должна быть ссылка, а просто div с атрибутом href :

```
<div data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</div>
```

Вот таким образом все отлично работает! Не знаю допустимо ли это из стороны корректности кода!

Comment: так-же можно вместо href использовать атрибут data-target